# Is there a small css 1 javascript function/library to retrieve elements?

Tags: javascript

Also do you know of some useful javascript tutorials?

Also is there a tutorial that explains the jquery library line by line?

Comment: Useful javascript tutorials to do what? Is there something specific you want to do? Or just learning javascript?

Answer (score 3):

Lots of information available at [jquery.com](http://jquery.com), including [How Jquery Works](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works), a list of [Tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials), and the [API documentation](http://api.jquery.com).  For general javascript stuff, I find that [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com) has a lot of information on [learning javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp), along with the ability to try things out yourself.  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) can be useful for trying out code, including frameworks, as well once you have a better handle on what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question:
Look at `document.getElementById`, `document.getElementsByTagName`, and `document.getElementsByName`

Google is your friend, here...

I recommend you actually learn JavaScript, the magical language that is magical, before you start wandering into the realms of jQuery, as in my opinion, you should learn the basics before you have things become simplified for you.

I should note that I do not hate jQuery users, but I believe that learning simple/traditional DOM manipulation is important.  Frameworks can come later.

Answer (score 0):

Make a good understanding of Javascript to understand jQuery and other magic libraries.